# Unable to sign into Messages on Mavericks

Tags: macos, messages, keychain

I'm unable to log into iMessage on my account in Mavericks.

Here's what Console.log shows:

```
5/23/14 9:50:15.996 AM identityservicesd[343]: [Warning]  *** Bad Request From Server ***
5/23/14 9:50:16.102 AM identityservicesd[343]: [Warning] Registration failed for Registration info (0x7fc19630fa80): [Registered: NO] [Type: AppleID] [Device Name: (null)] [Service Type: iMessage] [Env: (null)] [Main ID: n***@*******k.com] [Phone Number: n***@*******k.com] [AppleID: n***@*******k.com] [UserID: E:n***@*******k.com] [C2K: NO] [Push Token: <3fcb7834 a######2 0######6 4######5 c######0 9c0941f6 fe61af4a 3954a0fc>] [Region ID: R:US] [Base Number: +12*******17] [URIs: (null)] [Candidates: (null)] [Auth Cert: 0x0] [Reg Cert: 0x0] [Profile ID: D:120333617] [Auth Token: (null)]  [Auth User ID: (null)] [Heartbeat Date: (null)]   (Error: 9)
5/23/14 9:50:16.125 AM identityservicesd[343]: [Warning] Registration failed for Registration info (0x7fc19630fa80): [Registered: NO] [Type: AppleID] [Device Name: (null)] [Service Type: iMessage] [Env: (null)] [Main ID: n***@*******k.com] [Phone Number: n***@*******k.com] [AppleID: n***@*******k.com] [UserID: E:n***@*******k.com] [C2K: NO] [Push Token: <3fcb7834 a######2 0######6 4######5 c######0 9c0941f6 fe61af4a 3954a0fc>] [Region ID: R:US] [Base Number: +12*******17] [URIs: (null)] [Candidates: (null)] [Auth Cert: 0x0] [Reg Cert: 0x0] [Profile ID: D:120333617] [Auth Token: (null)]  [Auth User ID: (null)] [Heartbeat Date: (null)]   (Error: 9)
5/23/14 9:50:16.125 AM identityservicesd[343]: [Warning] Failed, server error => Disabling service
5/23/14 9:50:16.126 AM identityservicesd[343]: [Warning] Failed, server error => Disabling service
5/23/14 9:50:16.148 AM identityservicesd[343]: [Warning] Needs deletion: NO (Registration info (0x7fc19630fa80): [Registered: NO] [Type: AppleID] [Device Name: (null)] [Service Type: iMessage] [Env: (null)] [Main ID: n***@*******k.com] [Phone Number: n***@*******k.com] [AppleID: n***@*******k.com] [UserID: E:n***@*******k.com] [C2K: NO] [Push Token: <3fcb7834 a######2 0######6 4######5 c######0 9c0941f6 fe61af4a 3954a0fc>] [Region ID: R:US] [Base Number: +12*******17] [URIs: (null)] [Candidates: (null)] [Auth Cert: 0x0] [Reg Cert: 0x0] [Profile ID: D:120333617] [Auth Token: (null)]  [Auth User ID: (null)] [Heartbeat Date: (null)])
5/23/14 9:50:16.171 AM identityservicesd[343]: [Warning] Needs deletion: NO (Registration info (0x7fc19630fa80): [Registered: NO] [Type: AppleID] [Device Name: (null)] [Service Type: iMessage] [Env: (null)] [Main ID: n***@*******k.com] [Phone Number: n***@*******k.com] [AppleID: n***@*******k.com] [UserID: E:n***@*******k.com] [C2K: NO] [Push Token: <3fcb7834 a######2 0######6 4######5 c######0 9c0941f6 fe61af4a 3954a0fc>] [Region ID: R:US] [Base Number: +12*******17] [URIs: (null)] [Candidates: (null)] [Auth Cert: 0x0] [Reg Cert: 0x0] [Profile ID: D:120333617] [Auth Token: (null)]  [Auth User ID: (null)] [Heartbeat Date: (null)])
```

Here is what I've tried:

- Repair Permissions & Repair Disk
- Deleting what appears to be appropriate out of my Keychain (iMessage & iCloud Keys, etc.)
- Logging into a guest account makes iCloud/Messages work just fine (can send and receive messages).
- All of my other iCloud services just work fine.
- iMessages on my phone works fine as well.
- Run Keychain First Aid.
- Deleted some files from that pertain to identifyservicesd / soagent

  - ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.soagent/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.messageshelper.AccountInfoController.plist
  - ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.soagent/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.soagent.plist
- I'm using a MBP 15" Retina (not a mackintosh).
- Changing Apple ID Password. (on appleid.apple.com)

Answer (score 0):

Context: I have two login keychains, one from an old MBP and the new one from this machine.

After deleting anything that had to do with Messages/Apple ID (including encryption keys, certificates, etc.) and killing the imagent and identityservicesd processes, Messages finally let me log in:

- Apple ID n**@*********.com key (multiple of both public and private keys)
- A bunch of old @me.com stuff (anything)
- iMessage Encryption / Decryption Keys

Comment: Please use the edit button when you want to update or add details to your question. Submit an answer only when what you're submitting actually is one.